# correct language usage

Tags: idioms, vocabulary

Those clerics, who often have ***views on life which are in stark contrast to the Belgian lifestyle***, have been ***provoking identity crises in many immigrant youths***, making them vulnerable for radicalization.

I was wondering if the sentence above is correct. I'm not so sure about the two parts in italic. Is it better to say "Those clerics, who often have views on life in stark contrast to the Belgian *lifestyle*?..." and to provoke a crisis? would a native english speaker say that?

Thanks!

Comment: Both italic passages are grammatical.  Are you asking about whether the phrasing makes sense?  Do you think that life views and lifestyle are two incomparable things?  Or is it a matter of verbosity?  (Your rephrase cuts two words.) An identity crisis is a state of personal turmoil, and certainly one person could instigate such a state in another.  The google finds roughly 85K hits for "provoke a crisis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Those clerics, who often have views on life which are in stark contrast to the Belgian lifestyle, have been provoking identity crises in many immigrant youths, making them vulnerable for radicalization.

First set of commas are parenthetical.

> Those clerics (who often have views on life which are in stark contrast to the Belgian lifestyle) have been provoking identity crises in many immigrant youths, making them vulnerable for radicalization.

That means their contents can be removed and leave behind a viable sentence.

> Those clerics have been provoking identity crises in many immigrant youths, making them vulnerable for radicalization.

This leaves two independent clauses. You could make it two sentences.

> Those clerics have been provoking identity crises in many immigrant youths. Making them vulnerable for radicalization.

You could keep them close using a semicolon.

> Those clerics have been provoking identity crises in many immigrant youths; making them vulnerable for radicalization.

Or you can just use the comma.  It's a bit lazy but semicolons are not as popular as they could be.

So on the whole, there is nothing wrong with this punctuation.

Punctuation aside, I've have used 'vulnerable **to** radicalization'.  Only because I don't look at immigrant youths from the perspective of the clerics.